# No emit() method to be Called

Tags: node.js

I am learning Nodejs right now. I am confused to a partial of code from a textbook.

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var server = http.createServer().listen(8124);
server.on('request', function(request,response) {
   if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        // append data chunk to body
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });

        // data transmitted
        request.on('end', function () {
            var post = querystring.parse(body);
            console.log(post);
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end('Hello World\n');
        }); 
     }
});
console.log('server listening on 8214');
```

http.createServer returns a http.Server object which inherits from EventEmitter.
To be sure, The EventEmitter contain on and emit method. In this example, I only see the on method, and do not find any place to call the emit method. How the emit method is called or the event bind on on method is triggered? Does the emit method encapsulates in other method?

Comment: Why do you want to call the `emit` method?

Comment: What is your actual problem with this code?  You don't need to call the `emit` method in order to use a server object.  It calls it internally in order to create the `request` event.

Comment: @jfriend00 Could you offer the detail or documentation about internal call of emit method ? Where is it called?

Comment: @pipi - That's how events are triggered on an EventEmitter - that's how they work, so the very fact that there is a `request` event means somebody is calling `.emit('request', ....)` on it.  You can read the documentation for the EventEmitter object if you want to learn more about how it works or you can go look at [the source code for the http server object](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L532) and see the exact calls to `.emit()`.

Comment: @pipi - It sounds like you don't understand how a server object works.  You register an event listener for the `request` event.  When an incoming http request connects to the server, the server will then `.emit()` the `request` event and your listener will get called.  You don't `.emit()` anything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

emit function is not required to be called in this case. you can simply hit your url via postman.